# YouTrack 4.x - How do you sort all task by priority in their swimlanes in the agile board?

Tags: agile, youtrack

Like the title says, is there a way to sort all tasks within swimlanes by priority?

I thought you could do this via the search box up top by putting something like:

```
order by: priority
```

however it didn't seem to do anything (I used the auto complete bits so it seemed right)?

As currently we have critical bugs down the bottom and minor cosmetics at the top and we dont want to have to keep manually sorting them for developers to pick up.

Answer (score 4):

This is not quite what you are looking for, but may serve a similar purpose:

1. Create a board specifically for dealing with priorities -- I call mine "Priority Board".
2. Set the swimlane type to 'attribute'
3. Set the "Field to identify swimlane" to "Priority"
4. Checkmark all values in the "Field Values To Identify Swimlane" drop box, and click 'apply'

Voilà - Drag tasks between swimlanes to set their priority, and you have a nice clear view of the priorities and current state of various tasks -- unfortunately, their swimlanes in the normal view may not be so obvious.

Alternatively, you can set the field for color-coded cards to the 'priority' field.  Not quite the same as sorting, but still visually obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Grofit,

It's impossible to sort tasks by priority inside swimlane. 
So you can only sort thru all swimlanes. 
Also, I would like to recommend you to use following query another time, if you need to sort by priority:

```
sort by: Priority
```